# Why is my Flexbox leaving a huge gap at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So when ever I shrink the page to fit a mobile device it leaves a huge gap at the bottom.

I want it to just stack normally when it shrinks so it's one on top of the other.
without it leaving a huge gap at the bottom.

There is no gap at the bottom when it's sized for desktop use but as soon as I shrink it down, they stack but it also leaves a huge gap at the bottom.

This is what it's doing https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRIRt.jpg

```css
.song-box {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;

}

.flex-container {
    width: 1700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.flex-container img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.flex-container img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>


        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>

        <div class="song-box">
            <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51"
                alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>
</div>
```

the body

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(/images/party.jpg);
    /* background-size: 100%; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: converted your code blocks into a snippet. From the snippet, it's got nothing to do with the flexbox, probably the background image in the body or something

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem using the code you provided. No gap at bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/378rgyeh/

Comment: Updated the question and added where I set the background image

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the background image you are using is causing the gap at the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

and keep the height to auto on the background image. the background image should be defined by its content from what i see.

Also setting a definite width will cause the box to extend out to the right. Which will make flex-wrap never trigger because the viewport even though is smaller the box is still 1700px. I suggest using

```
.flex-container {
    max-width: 1700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

It should Wrap correctly leaving you with space at the bottom.